# Untick parent node when untick child node in tree view

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a tree view which has parent node and sub nodes.
When check parent node I'm checking all the sub nodes using this code.

```
 foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                node.Checked = nodeChecked;
                if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {                   
                    this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
                }
            }
```

Now what I want is , When unchecking a sub node ; I need to untick parent node.
How can I do this?
Which Event I have to use?

I'm using C# Windows application.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below mentioned method

```
private void UncheckParentNodes(TreeNodeCollection node)
{
    foreach (TreeNode n in node)
    {
        if (n.Parent == null && n.Nodes.Count == 0)
            n.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: With in that if I call ur method like this that is getting error.  UncheckParentNodes(e.Node); So how can I call that method?

Comment: The method accepts an argument of type `TreeNodeCollection`, so you must give it a collection of nodes. Use `e.Node.Nodes`.